# Test network latency from one machine to another (or to a specified target endpoint) over TCP?

Tags: networking, latency

Are there any free command line tools for testing network latency from a machine **A** to machine **B** over TCP where machine **A** is running linux?

I need to test for a large number of small e.g. GET requests against machine **B** from machine **A**.

I have looked at: `sockperf` but looks that it requires that I can install the client on machine  **A** (which is fine) and the server on **B** and I don't have the option to do the latter.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you try good ol' `ping` command? Issuing GET requests adds the server response time to the network latency.

Comment: I am not allowed to ping from the source machine so it needs to be at least TCP/UDP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use hping3 , already packaged in debian 
   https://packages.debian.org/buster/hping3

source 
   http://www.hping.org/

Example :

```
hping3 -S -p 80 www.stackexchange.com
```

You can use tcptraceroute , alread packaged in debian
   https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/tcptraceroute

source 
    https://github.com/mct/tcptraceroute

Example:

```
tcptraceroute  www.stackexchange.com 80
```

To do http benchamrk you can use `ab` from apache

https://packages.debian.org/buster/apache2-utils

```
ab -c2 -n 4  http://www.stackexchange.com/
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option that you have is to use wget, curl or a custom script and capture the traffic with wireshark/tcpdump and make a post analysis and check the latency and other QoS metrics